# Using a prolog DCG to find & replace - code review

Tags: prolog, dcg

I came up w/ the following code to replace all occurences of `Find` w/ `Replace` in `Request` & put the answer in `Result`.  This is using a DCG, so they are all lists of character codes.  The predicate that client code would use is `substitute`.

```
findReplace(_, _, [], []) -->
    [].  % The end.
findReplace(Find, Replace, Result, ResultRest) -->
    Find,  % Found Find.
    { append(Replace, Intermediate, Result) },  % Put in Replace in Find's place.
    !,  % Make sure we don't backtrack & interpret Find as the next case.
    findReplace(Find, Replace, Intermediate, ResultRest).
findReplace(Find, Replace, [ C | Intermediate ], ResultRest) -->
    [ C ],  % Any other character.
    findReplace(Find, Replace, Intermediate, ResultRest).

substitute(Find, Replace, Request, Result):-
    phrase(findReplace(Find, Replace, Result, []), Request).
```

This works in SWI-Prolog.  Does anyone have any comments on how I could improve it?  I'm learning how to use DCG's & difference lists.  E.g., I put in the cut so that, after finding `Find`, prolog doesn't ever backtrack & interpret that as an ordinary character in the `[ C ]` case.  Is this needed, or is there a more declarative way of doing so?

Another question - is there a predicate already available to do the same thing that substitute does, maybe on atoms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider using semicontext notation to replace subsequences in DCGs:

```
eos([], []).

replace(_, _) --> call(eos), !.
replace(Find, Replace), Replace -->
        Find,
        !,
        replace(Find, Replace).
replace(Find, Replace), [C] -->
        [C],
        replace(Find, Replace).

substitute(Find, Replace, Request, Result):-
        phrase(replace(Find, Replace), Request, Result).
```

Example:

```
?- substitute("a", "b", "atesta", R), atom_codes(A, R).
R = [98, 116, 101, 115, 116, 98],
A = btestb.
```

Also, underscores_are_much_more_readable thanMixedCaseNamesAsYouSee.

Comment: This is ingenious.  BTW, I noticed that this expands to the following.
replace(_, _, A, B) :-
        call(eos, A, C), !,
        B=C.
replace(A, D, B, F) :-
        phrase(A, B, C), !,
        E=C,
        replace(A, D, E, G),
        phrase(D, F, G).
replace(B, C, A, E) :-
        A=[F|D],
        replace(B, C, D, G),
        E=[F|G].

substitute(A, B, C, D) :-
        phrase(replace(A, B), C, D).
eos([], []).
Is this tail recursive?  There is a `phrase` call after the 1st recursive replace call & a list binding after the 2nd.

Comment: In the example, the phrase/3 will translate and execute the "a" and "b". The solution is not that efficient, since the translation is redone over and over. Not sure what the fix would be.

Answer (score 2):

About the second question, i.e. working with atoms, I wrote this utility perusing [atomic_list_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3)

```
%%  replace_word(+Old, +New, +Orig, -Replaced)
%%  is det.
%
%   string replacement
%   doesn't fail if not found
%
replace_word(Old, New, Orig, Replaced) :-
    atomic_list_concat(Split, Old, Orig),
    atomic_list_concat(Split, New, Replaced).
```

Example:

```
?- replace_word(a, b, atesta, X).
X = btestb.
```