# Is this code generated by expanding a Prolog DCG tail-recursive?

Tags: prolog, dcg

The following code is a DCG to replace all occurences of `Find` w/ `Replace` in `Request` & put the answer in `Result`.  Thanks to mat, for the code, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392725/using-a-prolog-dcg-to-find-replace-code-review).

```
eos([], []).

replace(_, _) --> call(eos), !.
replace(Find, Replace), Replace -->
        Find,
        !,
        replace(Find, Replace).
replace(Find, Replace), [C] -->
        [C],
        replace(Find, Replace).

substitute(Find, Replace, Request, Result):-
        phrase(replace(Find, Replace), Request, Result).
```

In SWI-Prolog, this expands to the following.

```
replace(_, _, A, B) :-
        call(eos, A, C), !,
        B=C.
replace(A, D, B, F) :-
        phrase(A, B, C), !,
        E=C,
        replace(A, D, E, G),
        phrase(D, F, G).
replace(B, C, A, E) :-
        A=[F|D],
        replace(B, C, D, G),
        E=[F|G].

substitute(A, B, C, D) :-
        phrase(replace(A, B), C, D).

eos([], []).
```

Is this code tail-recursive? There is a call to `phrase` after the recursive call to `replace` in the 2nd definition of the predicate `replace`.  There's also `E=[F|G]` after the recursive call to `replace` in the 3rd definition of `replace`.  I thought that, if the recursive calls were made last, the code would be tail-recursive.  If the generated code isn't tail-recursive, is there any way to get Prolog to generate tail-recursive code?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above code contains quite complex constructs like a very far reaching generalization of a semicontext. Please note that above, both `Find` and `Replace` can be general non-terminals - not only lists.

So let's consider a simpler case:

```
iseq([]) --> [].
iseq([E|Es]) --> iseq(Es), [E].
```

which expands in many Prologs to:

```
iseq([], Xs, Xs).
iseq([E|Es], Xs0,Xs) :-
   iseq(Es, Xs0,Xs1),
   Xs1 = [E|Xs].
```

This isn't tail recursive either, but it can be made to be so by exchanging the two goals.
Still, many consider above translation preferable, since it obviously retains certain desirable properties and also leads to a frequently more efficient execution.